# Problem installing ntop on FreeBSD 6.2

Tags: freebsd, rrdtool, configuration, ntop

I'm following the instructions at http://www.ntop.org/download.html.

At some point during the `./configure` phase of the install, I get this error message:

`configure: error: Unable to find RRD at /usr/local/rrdtool: please use --with-rrd-home=DIR`

I run `which rrdtool` and I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/rrdtool
```

...so I run: `./configure --with-rrd-home=/usr/local/bin/rrdtool`

The installation continues, until it fails at the same spot, same error. I've tried a bunch of varying paths, like:

```
`./configure --with-rrd-home=/usr/local/bin/`
`./configure --with-rrd-home=/usr/local/bin`
`[...]`
`./configure --with-rrd-home=/usr`
```

... as I read in a suggestion while Googling the problem.

If it matters, I don't have root access on this machine. It's a dedicated server at my web host.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even better than all of the previous answers, why are you trying to install this by hand?

The ports tree contains ntop:

http://www.freshports.org/net/ntop/

So if you have the ports tree installed (if not, check the [FreeBSD Handbook on using ports](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/ports-using.html))

The ports tree is an amazing feature for FreeBSD in that it does the dependency tracking and compiles said dependencies for you. The version in the ports tree is outdated by 2 versions from what I can see, generally a nice email to the port maintainer can help you solve that issue!

Edit: Re-read your question and it seems that you are not running as root, how are you planning on getting access to a bpf device to log packets?

Comment: Thank you for saying that. ;-) Why use FreeBSD at all when you do not take advantage of ports.

Comment: +1, he'll need root access to install from the Ports tree, and the easiest/quickest way would be `pkg_add -r ntop`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just "./configure --with-rrd-home=/usr/local"?

Comment: It should be "./configure --with-rrd-home=/usr/local/bin".

Comment: No, I'm actually suggesting he leave off the /bin suffix - usually the home of an app is the base directory (like /usr or /usr/local).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to symlink (without root or sudo access you might not be able to do this neither)? On your shell:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/rrdtool /usr/local/rrdtool
```

One thing though, if you do not have root on the box, your usage of ntop will be limited. The errors you see might be caused by that fact.

Comment: "I don't have root access on this machine" - Can't write to /usr/local without root access (by default).

Answer (score -1):

if you don't change rrdtool default installation address, you should use --with-rrd-home=/opt/rrdtool-V which V is your rrdtool verion number.

Comment: There's no `/opt` folder in FreeBSD; and the default location would be `/usr/local/bin`